# list of function with several parameters python

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a list of the same function called with different parameters, something like this:

```
def func1(num):
    print("{}".format(num))

fl = [func1(1),func1(2),func1(3)]

for f in fl: 
    fl()
```

i got an error saying that 'list' object is not callable.

now, this works:

```
def func1():
    print 1
def func2():
    print 2
def func3():
    print 3

fl = [func1,func2,func3]

for f in fl:
   f()
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

functions = [partial(func1, i) for i in range(1, 4)]

for fun in functions:
    fun()
```

In your first example, I'm assuming that `fl()` is a typo, and you meant `f()` (because otherwise you'll be calling a `list` object, which isn't callable).

You know that `func1(1)` is calling the function and the result of this call is returned, so that in `res = func1(1)` the variable `res` will be the *result* of executing the function.. So, that list `[func1(1), func1(2), ...]` is a list of what this function *returns*. The function returns `None`, which isn't callable, that's why your code failed.

You want to *call* the function (not the result of calling the function!) with different arguments, and that's exactly what `functools.partial` is there for.

Comment: Can you explain briefly what's happening? OP seems to be having difficulty understanding the difference between a function and the output of a function (which is `None` in OP's first example).

Comment: this is exactly what i need :)

Answer (score 1):

From the code:

```
for f in f1:
    f1()
```

Explanation:

As you defined `f1` as of type `list` and you are using that variable as function call. But python expects the function name should be a `string` type. So got the error `list() type is not callable`

But when you changed code to :

```
for f in f1:
    f()
```

here the `f` is of type `string` so python validated the type and so it didn't throw error

Answer (score 1):

First, you're calling `fl()` which is trying to call the list as a function. that doesn't work.

In Python, putting `()` after a function evaluates the function and provides the return value. This means `fl = [func1(1),func1(2),func1(3)]` means "Create a list, and put the result of calling func1(1), func1(2), and func1(3)"

If you want to call the function later, then you can put the parameter into the list and walk through the list, or you can bind.

```
f = func1 # storing the function as a variable
fl = [1,2,3]

for v in fl: 
    f(v)
```

then you can do something like use lambda to bind:

```
f = func1 # storing the function as a variable
fl = [lambda :f(1), lambda :f(2), lambda :f(3)]

for v in fl: 
    v() # v is bound to the parameters, so you don't need to use a param
```